# Hibernate Mapping throws Constraint violation

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate

I have a database structure where many to many mapping is required. I have implemented it using the `@ManyToMany` annotation as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="trans.documentfiles")
public class DocumentFile extends GenericEntity
{
    private DocumentType documentType;
    private DocumentFormat documentFormat;
    private Set<DocumentGroup> docgroups;

    /**
     * @return the documentType
     */
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "filetypeid", nullable = false)
    public DocumentType getDocumentType()
    {
        return documentType;
    }
    /**
     * @param documentType the documentType to set
     */
    public void setDocumentType(DocumentType documentType)
    {
        this.documentType = documentType;
    }
    /**
     * @return the docgroups
     */
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "files")
    public Set<DocumentGroup> getDocgroups()
    {
        return docgroups;
    }
    /**
     * @param docgroups the docgroups to set
     */
    public void setDocgroups(Set<DocumentGroup> docgroups)
    {
        this.docgroups = docgroups;
    }
}
```

DocumentGroup.java is as follows

```
@Entity
@Table(name="trans.document")
public class DocumentGroup extends GenericEntity
{    
    private Set<DocumentFile> files = new HashSet<DocumentFile>();    
    /**
     * @return the files
     */
    @ManyToMany( fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL  )
    @JoinTable(name = "trans.documentlink",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "documentid", referencedColumnName="id")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "fileid", referencedColumnName="id")})
    public Set<DocumentFile> getFiles()
    {
        return files;
    }
    /**
     * @param files the files to set
     */
    public void setFiles(Set<DocumentFile> files)
    {
        this.files =  files;
    }
}
```

I have created relationships between the `DocumentFile` table and `DocumentType` tables in sql. I have not created any relationship between `DocumentFile` and `DocumentGroup` in sql. I want to delete records from the `ocumentLinks` table without deleting either the `DocumentGroup` record or the `DocumentFile` record nor the `DocumentType` record. I want to delete the parents in a separate thread.

Whenever my code for delete runs I am getting a foreign key constraint violation for the `DocumentType` record.

The code for delete is as follows

```
@Override
public boolean deleteOnlyLinks(long documentId, String nodeId)
{
    Criteria docFile = null;
    try
    {
        docFile = getCriteria(DocumentGroup.class);
        docFile.createAlias("files", "file");
        docFile.add(Restrictions.eq("file.id", documentId));
        docFile.add(Restrictions.eq("nodeId", nodeId));
        List<DocumentObjectLink> lst =  docFile.list();
        /*for (DocumentObjectLink documentObjectLink : lst)
        {*/
            getCrntSession().delete(lst.get(0));
        //}
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        logger.debug("Error while deleting" + documentId);
        throw new DMSException("Error while deleting" + documentId,ErrorCode.DELETE,e);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Please let me know how to go about this..

Thanks

EDIT::

```
1:35:11.706 E|SqlExceptionHelper                      |The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_documentfiles_documenttype". The conflict occurred in database "DMS", table "trans.documentfiles", column 'filetypeid'.
```

Comment: What is the stacktrace?

Comment: any pointers?? any hints??

Comment: Exception is throwing because you are trying to delete records which are constrained with foreign key and it's not good behaviour according to me.